# TestRail API returned HTTP 500 (No additional error message received)

Tags: testrail

I'm using TR version 5.6.0.3853; DB version 189.
I'm using for months TR API get requests (/index.php?/api/v2/get_cases/) suddenly, start reciving generic 500 error.
Tried rebooting the server nothing helps, somebody face issue like this? how can I identify the root cause?

Comment: Is there anything in sever logs?

Comment: It has been solved with this:
reviewing the following document and your PHP settings to see if this resolves the issue:

http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-faq/system-memory-limit